# Working With Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

In Joomla which extension are best for displaying titles of the banners bottom of the banner.Means not in the Banner out side of the banner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to banners from the banners component?

Comment: The question was not clear ? what you want actually ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple fix to better banner control I recommend you use the Custom HTML Module and publish it in the same position as that banner.

If your using Google Adsense for example you'd add something like

```
 <script>
     Your Adsense Code Here
 </script>
 <h3>Your Bottom Title Here</h3>
```

Ensure that you disable the title field in the module, the banner component is ok in Joomla but nothing beats full control by using Custom HTML. If you find that Custom HTML module is filtering your scripts and so on, search the Joomla extension for custom HTML that supports non-filtering. I believe Flexi is one of those.

Hope this helps!